# How to map URL /foo/* to a static file /foo.html on Google App Engine?

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I have a question about Google App Engine (Java). I would like to map a URL pattern `/foo/*` to one static file `/foo.html` (so that requesting `/foo/bar` or `/foo/baz` would return the contents of `/foo.html`). The static file `foo.html` contains javascript that populates the page with content based on the actual request URL.

I know how to use `web.xml` to map a wildcard URL to a servlet, but I haven't found anything similar for static files.

My `appengine-web.xml` has `<public-root>/static</public-root>`.

The best solutions I've come up so far is to map `/foo/*` to a servlet that serves the `foo.html` as a JSP page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to use a servlet, you can map the url pattern directly to a jsp, and have only html in it:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>foo.jsp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/foo.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>foo.jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks @moshe-shaham, I see what you mean. The requests would still hit the application server, though. I was hoping to serve the HTML as a real static file: [App Engine serves static files from dedicated servers and caches that are separate from the application servers.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_files_and_resource_files).

Comment: @user2962393 i don't think it's possible without application server. another option is to specify the url by hashtag: `http://www.example.com/#url/to/path`. this way it serves index.html regardless of the path

Comment: On App Engine this will work only with .jsp files. That is, you can't map an .html file this way (only on the dev server).

Comment: This is BS because its possible in python: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following 2 workarounds:

**Option 1**

Let's say you want to map `/foo` to an html file...

1. Create a directory `foo` in your `webapp` directory
2. Create an html file `index.html` in the `foo` directory
3. In your `appengine-web.xml` add the following:

   ```
   <static-files>  
     <include path="/foo"/> 
   </static-files>
   ```

Now deploy and visit `/foo` and it should serve the index.html in the foo directory

**Option 2**

Use an app.yaml for java as described here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml

and use static file handlers: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

Comment: option 1 worked for me while the accepted answer did not allow the use of .html's